# Starting all mod_wsgi processes

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, mod-wsgi

mod_wsgi processes seems to be lazily started i.e. on request. However, I prefer to start all the processes from the beginning because the process start up time is long. Is there a configuration option for this? or a way around it?

Here is the process configuration in case it was relevant:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=user group=user processes=30 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup myapp
```

Note: I'm running multiple processes each with one thread in daemon mode. apache is compiled with MPM worker

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might well find that the delay isn't the time taking to spin-up the processes per se. But instead the time it takes for them to load and start delivering your app.

You can use the [`WSGIImportScript`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIImportScript) directive to preload processes. Which may in turn negate the delays you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Read my answer to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702562/speeding-up-the-first-page-load-in-django